# Unable to force Python syntax-highlighting

Tags: support, status-completed, markdown, syntax-highlighting

I have asked a question related to web2py—an open-source Python web-framework—that includes a code snippet.

Unfortunately it didn't syntax highlight by default, so—following [the docs](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting)—I added the following to precede the code: `<!-- language: lang-py -->`

Unfortunately it had no affect. Please fix this bug.

(For evidence; see my question: [Generate a nested CRUD form](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10585663))

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You just needed a blank line after the `<!-- language: lang-py -->`. :)

Comment: Quick aside for the 11 minutes until I can accept your answer: how would I go about getting Python added to the tag inference for web2py?

Comment: @A.T. Normally, you'd just make a meta post about it or flag a question and ask a moderator to set it up. I went ahead and just set it in this case, though. Seems straightforward. :)